# including kendoui in asp.net master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Question Summary:  How do I include kendoui js files using the ScriptReference method in a master page?

If I include the kendo.js files in the head of the master page, since the jQuery files are being included later the KendoUI extension to jQuery is overridden.  This is the code in the default asp.net application generated by visual studio 2012 that is including jQuery stuff in the master pages:

How do I include kendoui js files using the ScriptReference method in a master page?

I searched this everywhere  but have not come up with a clean solution.  SO I think this may be value added for the kendoui and generally for the asp.net community.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not change the order of the script that you included?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET web forms or ASP.NET MVC with the Web Forms view engine? You have tagged the question with MVC but this looks and sounds like web forms.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  All you have to do is the following in Site.master:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
```

...include jQuery etc...
                <%--Site Scripts--%>

earlier I was trying to use the scriptreference with a name attribute,  which was problematic.

Thanks You.  Hope it helps others.